# What is the best way to change the vertex stride between draw call in Vulkan

Tags: vulkan, vertex-buffer, stride

I am trying to create Vulkan support for my DX12 GameEngine, however, I've run into a problem and am not sure how to solve it.

I have two kinds of meshes: a regular mesh which contains vertex position, texcoord, normal... and the other which extends it and also continues armature contact data like bones_ids and weights.

In DirectX 12 you have the gpu-command `ID3D12GraphicsCommandList::IASetVertexBuffers` which also allows you to change the vertex buffer stride dynamically before every mesh's draw commands. However, in my understanding of Vulkan you should define the vertex stride explicitly at the pipeline creation time, or add a appropriate dynamic state element `VK_DYNAMIC_STATE_VERTEX_INPUT_EXT` to change dynamically the entire vertex input layer.

Thus, is there a way to change dynamically only the vertex stride without changing all of the vertex input? Perhaps the right way is to create to pipeline state for each kind of mesh?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.